# Create List with only one class member

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of this class:

```
public class Data
{
   public string name {get; set;}
   public int width {get; set;}
}
```

And I want to make a method that return a list of only the name property. Like this:

```
public List<string> GetAllNames()
{ return MyDataList<name>.ToList(); }
```

So, if I have this list:

1. `name` = Jon - `width` = 10
2. `name` = Jack - `width` = 25

I want the following list:

1. `name` = Jon
2. `name` = Jack

Is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
public List<string> GetAllNames()
{
    return MyDataList.Select(i => i.name).ToList();
}
```

Comment: As a note, if you return a List<string> then you're going to basically duplicate the entire list. This can take time/memory if you have a large list. If you switch to using IEnumerable<string> and then don't do the .ToList(), then you will get a lazy list that is almost free to create, and will consume very little (< 100bytes) of space

Comment: @TimothyBaldridge: True. It's also worth noting that if you go the `IEnumerable` route, it will be re-evaluated each time you iterate across it. Your IEnumerable also becomes tied to the original set of objects, so it will prevent the garbage collector from cleaning up all the `Data` objects even if you only ever plan to use the names from them. Furthermore, if `MyDataList` changes, the returned `IEnumerable` would change, and may throw an exception if it's being used in a separate thread. Often none of this matters, but it's always good to understand what's happening under the covers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 3.5 (VS2008) or later then use Extension methods:

```
public class Data { String Name; Int32 Width; }
public List<Data> MyData = new List<Data>();

public static IEnumerable<String> GetNames(this List<Data> data) {
    foreach(Data d in data) yield return d.Name;
}
// or use Linq to return a concrete List<String> implementation rather than IEnumerable.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<string> GetAllNames()
{ 
    return myDataList.Select(item => item.name).ToList();
}
```